# SQLSTATE Error Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users_sessions'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, mysql-error-1066

I've got an error with a simple query using a join.

My query :

```
SELECT users_sessions.user_id AS users_sessions_user_id,
       users.last_name AS users_last_name,
       users.first_name AS users_first_name 
FROM prefix_users_sessions AS users_sessions,
     prefix_users AS users INNER JOIN 
     users_sessions 
     ON users.id = users_sessions.user_id
```

My error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
>   table/alias: 'users_sessions'

I don't understand the message... i don't see where the alias is used more that one.

Who can help me to solve this problem ?

Thankz by advance for your help.

--SOLVED--

The good query is the following :

```
    SELECT users_sessions.id AS users_sessions_id,
           users_sessions.user_id AS users_sessions_user_id,
           users.lastname AS users_lastname, users.firstname AS
           users_firstname
    FROM prefix_users_sessions AS users_sessions
           JOIN prefix_users AS users ON users.id = users_sessions.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `from` clause is all messed up.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Also, use shorter table aliases so your query is easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT us.user_id AS users_sessions_user_id,
       u.last_name AS users_last_name,
       u.first_name AS users_first_name 
FROM prefix_users_sessions us INNER JOIN
     prefix_users  u 
     ON u.id = us.user_id;
```

This assumes that you don't really have a table called `users_sessions`, and the intention is to use a table called `prefix_users_sessions`.

Comment: Thankz for your lights Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You use name `users_sessions` twice.
First as the alias of `prefix_users_sessions` and then as a normal table in the `INNER JOIN`. Also try to use `INNER JOIN`s and not selecting from two tables simultaneously e.g (in your query).:

```
FROM prefix_users_sessions AS users_sessions, prefix_users AS users
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified table **prefix_users_sessions** twice

```
SELECT  users_sessions.user_id AS users_sessions_user_id,
        users.last_name AS users_last_name,
        users.first_name AS users_first_name
FROM    prefix_users_sessions AS users_sessions
        INNER JOIN prefix_users AS users 
            ON users.id = users_sessions.user_id
```